# Show more or less content based on size of window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an main window with multiple ContentControls. They resize according to the window. And the size of their content is also resized to fill their size.
In my case an ContentControl may contain a diagram, but if window is resized big, and the ContentControl grows, then I would also like to show an table of numbers along with the diagram, if size of ContentControl gets big enough.
In other words, instead of resize the content (bigger/smaler font for example), I would like to show more or less content.
I use Caliburn Micro and could make multiple views for the same ViewModel, but I feel there might be other ways to do it.

Comment: can you share the code what you have done so far?

Comment: That's very generic and common problem: define view layout properly. You can use `Margin` or containers (e.g. `Grid` with autosized columns/rows) to **position** your content, `ViewBox` to **scale**, `ScrollView` to access invisible portion of big content. There are also multiple ways to stretch (resize) content: using `HorizontalAlignment`/`VerticalAlignment`, `Grid` with stars units. Start with making sketch of layout. If you have specific problem - show us sketch, your attempt and what is the problem. Currently question is too broad and generic.

Comment: Thanks. @MKMohanty, I have not tried yet. I was on the way to simply create multiple Views for the same ViewModel.@Sinatr.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [ViewBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx) control is the answer you're looking for.

It Defines a content decorator that can stretch and scale a single child to fill the available space.